# Properties of Magnus expansion

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations

The Magnus expansion $\Omega(t, t_0) = \sum^\infty_k \Omega_k(t,t_0)$ is so that the solution

$$
Y(t) = e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}\,Y_0,
$$

solves an ODE

$$
Y'(t) = A(t)\,Y(t), \qquad Y(t_0) = Y_0.
$$

Consequently, we know that $d e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}/dt = A(t)\, e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}$.

I am asking if the following properties hold in general and how to prove if true:

1. $d \Omega(t,t_0)/dt = A(t)$? (I think no)
2. $e^{\Omega(t,t_0)} = e^{\Omega(t, s)}\,e^{\Omega(s, t_0)}$?
3. $d e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}/dt_0 = -e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}\,A(t_0)$?

---

References of Magnus expansion: [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_expansion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer these questions it it helpful to write
$$e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}={\cal T}\exp\left(\int_{t_0}^t A(t')dt'\right),\;\;t\geq t_0,$$
in terms of the time ordering operator ${\cal T}$, such that a product of noncommuting operators $A(t_1)A(t_2)\ldots$ is ordered in the way that $t_1\geq t_2\geq\cdots$. By construction, the time ordering operator commutes with $d/dt$ or $d/dt_0$, and we can differentiate the exponent of the integral without worrying about the operator ordering.

1. We thus have
   $$\frac{d}{dt} e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}=A(t)e^{\Omega(t,t_0)},$$
   but *not* $d\Omega/dt=A(t)$.
2. If $t\geq s\geq t_0$, we have indeed
   $$e^{\Omega(t,t_0)} = e^{\Omega(t, s)}\,e^{\Omega(s, t_0)}.$$
3. We also have
   $$\frac{d}{dt_0} e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}=-e^{\Omega(t,t_0)}A(t_0).$$

Comment: 2 and 3 hold by seeing $Y(t)=e^{\Omega(t,t_0)} Y_0$ solves the ODE?

Comment: all three items hold by virtue of the time ordering definition: you use that, given two functionals $f$ and $g$ of the time dependent operator $A(t)$, you have ${\cal T}(fg)={\cal T}(f){\cal T}(g)$ if the times that contribute to $f$ are all greater than the times that contribute to $g$.

Comment: Thanks! Would you like to elaborate/cite on the time ordering operator? I am not familiar with it and googling does not give any useful results.

Comment: it is also called "path ordering", see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path-ordering and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential ; it's one of these notations invented by physicists that make life easier...